# Tuition cost over time

Tags: reference-request, tuition

I am wondering if anybody knows of a datasource that makes available tuition cost over time (annually) for US institutions.  I am particularly interested in the cost of graduate school expense.

Comment: http://nces.ed.gov/programs/digest/d13/tables/dt13_330.50.asp Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: @Compass -- This is what I am needing.  Elevate your comment to an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The National Center for Educational Statistics publishes reports mostly yearly regarding tuition fees as part of its [Digest of Educational Statistics](http://nces.ed.gov/programs/digest/d12/).

[Relevant Table](http://nces.ed.gov/programs/digest/d13/tables/dt13_330.50.asp) for graduate admissions from the most recent report. Information appears to go back to the 80s even with the [1995 report](http://nces.ed.gov/programs/digest/d95/dtab308.asp). Earlier data might be available from the Department of Education itself on request.

[Professional degree type 1988 to 2010](http://nces.ed.gov/programs/digest/d95/dtab308.asp) Of note is that most fields have ballooned in cost the past three decades.